# Remote transfer file once to two different directories on remote

Tags: rsync, scp

Using `scp` or `rsync`, is it possible to copy a file from your local to two or more different directories on a remote server but only sending the file once?

I would *prefer* not to ssh in manually after and `cp` the files but will accept this as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do this via scp or via rsyc. You have to run the command multiple times. You can do something like

`for HOST in server1 server2 server3; do
    scp somefile $HOST:~/somedir/
done`

There are efficient utilities to achieve this so install something like  `parallel, parallel-scp, pssh` etc

Or if this involves large number of remote location i will prefer using perl to multithread the process.

Answer (score 0):

`scp` is simple tool. Alternative could be `parallel-scp`, but it would probably copy the files twice.

Only thing I can think of is to "simplify" it by merging that into single `ssh` command:

```
cat local_file | ssh host "cat /remote/file; cp /remote/file /second/path/file"
```